# How to make javascript timer reload

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code of Javascript that i got from a forum for my html page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Countdown</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
// set minutes
var mins = 0.1;

// calculate the seconds (don't change this! unless time progresses at a different speed for you...)
var secs = mins * 60;
function countdown() {
    setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
}

function Decrement() {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
        seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
        // if less than a minute remaining

        if (seconds < 59) {
            seconds.value = secs;

        } else {
            minutes.value = getminutes();
            seconds.value = getseconds();
        }
        secs--;
        setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);

    }
}
function getminutes() {
    // minutes is seconds divided by 60, rounded down
    mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
    return mins;

}
function getseconds() {
    // take mins remaining (as seconds) away from total seconds remaining
    return secs-Math.round(mins *60);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="timer">
    Minutes:<input id="minutes" type="text" style="width: 14px; border: none; background-color:none; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">:<input id="seconds" type="text" style="width: 26px; border: none; background-color:none; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;"> seconds.
</div>
<script>
countdown();
</script>
```

My question is how can i make it reload when the time is up. so if seconds and minuets = 0, it would reload.

Or if you have a better simple times, please show me how :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following lines in countdown:

```
if (getseconds() == 0 && getminutes() == 0) {
   document.location.reload(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more simple (and more beautiful) solution:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Countdown</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
// set minutes
var mins = 0.1;

// calculate the seconds (don't change this! unless time progresses at a different speed for you...)
var secs = mins * 60;

function countdown() {
    secs = secs - 1;

    if (secs < 0) {
        document.location.reload(true);
    } else {
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = secs;
        window.setTimeout('countdown()', 1000);
    }
}

window.onload = countdown;
</script>
</head>
<body>
    Reloading in <span id="countdown">&nbsp;</span> seconds.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I didn't see, that you just want a reload :)